# ¿Cómo modificar las plantillas de email de notificación de GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

Hace unos días estoy buscando cómo modificar las plantillas de notificación de GitLab pero no he encontrado nada en la red sobre cómo poder hacerlo.

En la documentación y en algún foro que se habla de esto, he podido encontrar que hay un menú en el panel de admin que permite enviar un texto custom para todos los mails, pero esto no entraría dentro de lo que yo necesito.

Los emails mandados por GitLab cuando alguien hace una petición de merge o bien el merge son escasos y no deja claro entendimiento.

Email petición request:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí no indica que es una petición de merge, unicamente muestra las branches implicadas y el número de petición entiendo. Es algo confuso el mail.

Email merge completed:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí el texto es más descriptivo indicando que le merge se ha realizado pero igualmente aparece el número en la parte superior que es confuso.

¿Alguna idea de como poder editar las plantillas de mail?

ACTUALIZACIÓN:

Parece ser que esta opción se está reclamando a gitlab por la necesidad de la comunidad. De mientras es posible editar manualmente las themplates que renderizan el html para el email.

Por poner un ejemplo, podemos editar la plantilla de email de notificación de merge y añadir el texto que nosotros queramos. En este caso el fichero para este fin se encuentra en

`embedded/service/gitlab-rails/app/views/notify/merged_merge_request_email.html.haml`

Comment: El número corresponde al número de la merge request

Comment: Gracias por la edición. Si entiendo que es el número pero me gustaría poder añadir el texto "Merge request" por ejemplo, para poder ver claramente y rápido el motivo del email.

Comment: Es algo que la comunidad está pidiendo pero que GitLab de momento no ofrece: [Can I change default email notification template?](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/19743). En la [documentación](https://docs.gitlab.com) no encuentro nada y tampoco en el código en sí. Veo [en otro foro](https://gitlab.uservoice.com/forums/176466-deprecated-feedback-forum/suggestions/6009318-make-the-email-templates-editable-customizable) que directamente contestaron _We are open to improving the templates (please submit merge requests), we're not open to make them editable_. Es decir, que nanay.

Comment: ¿I hardcodeando texto en las templates podría ser? he estado mirando los ficheros y haciendo alguna prueba pero no me ha funcionado. Hablo de los ficheros ubicados aquí: /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/app/views/notify. La url donde he encontrado esta información: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/19743. He probado a editar por ejemplo la plantilla "new_merge_reque....html.haml" pero no hay resultado, el email llega como siempre.

Comment: Dicho lo cual, acabo de encontrar el fichero `embedded/service/gitlab-rails/app/views/notify/merged_merge_request_email.html.haml` que contiene exactamente este texto. Si también lo tienes, intenta editarlo, reiniciar GitLab y ver si lo coge. ¡Haz backups! Y seguramente se perderá la info cuando hagas un update

Comment: Voy a probar a reiniciar el servicio, comento algo en cuanto haga la prueba!

Comment: ¡Anda! Encontramos el mismo fichero a la vez jaja. Prueba y nos cuentas ;-)

Comment: Confirmo que funciona, si harcodeas texto en el fichero del que estabamos hablando y reinicias el gitlab (sudo gitlab-ctl restart) funciona correctamente. Yo he editado el fichero new_merge_request_email.html.haml. Lo suyo demás sería ver si se tienen disponibles segun que variables para completar la información en el fichero (nombre de usuario que realiza el merge, si esta pendiente el master de actulizar etc)